# Is it possible to have only client side columns for bi-directional database synchronization when using a database cache?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, microsoft-sync-framework

When you are create a database cache and want to do bi-directional synchronization I have read that you should use GUID's as a key instead of a unique Id to prevent clashes during synchronization.  There will be a performance hit though so is this a required trade off when using synchronization?

As well it looks like you need to have columns added to your tables on the server (ie. creationdate and lastedited date) in order to enable bi-directional syncing.  I will not be able to do this so is it possible to do this with these columns in the client side database only?  I do not understand why they HAVE to be on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not required to use GUIDs. it's only advised when you're using identity columns which can lead to duplicate values when you upload to the server unless you've partitioned your identity key values between clients and servers such that the identity values dont overlap.

am assuming you're referring to using the Local Database Cache wizard to generate the sync code, the datetime columns are for change tracking. It's there so sync framework knows what has changed in the server.  If you cant add columns to the table, then use Sql Change Tracking.

Comment: It does not look like I will be able to do what I want since I do not have access to modify the SQL server in any way.  I was hoping there was a framework that could use client only tables to track its changes.  I guess I will have to come up with some sort of checkout system to avoid multiple users changing the same set of data.  Then I can update all rows for that project during the check in process and not have to worry about any complicated sync conditions or conflicts.

Comment: dont you have any other column in your table than can tell if a row has changed? increasing or sequential numbers?

Comment: They are all string or numeric values that describe something or indicate a quantity.  There are no rows that would save a date or a version incrementally that could be used to identify if a row has changed.